# I need to pass JS var into php var inside JS function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to pass a javascript variable value to a php variable and both of them are inside a javascript function!

```
function addOrderItem(selectedRow) {
    var rowData = productsTable.row(selectedRow).data();
    if(rowData.type == "collection") {
        var orderItemBlock = "<div id='TextBoxDiv'>"+
            "<input type='button' class='accordion' value='"+rowData.id+" "+rowData.name+"'>"+
            "<div class='panel'>"+
                "<?php"+
                    "$collectionID=000;"+ //I need to pass JS var "rowData.id" value here
                "?>"+
            "</div>"+
        "</div>";
    }
}
```

I need to pass the value of rowData.id to $collectionID

Inside the php section, I'm fetching values from database to print it and it works fine!

I tried the following but nothing is working!

```
$collectionID = "<script>rowData.id</script>";
$collectionID = "<script>document.writeln(rowData.id);</script>";
```

Comment: PHP is a backend language, Javascript is a frontend language. I'm not sure what type of setup you have, but, unless you're using NodeJS (Javascript in the backend), you can't write PHP code with JavaScript

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the way you seek, although you can try using AJAX with a POST request. Hope I helped! -CM

Comment: Inside the php section, I'm fetching values from database to print it and it works fine!

Comment: @AhmedHamdy php runs on your server and sends the result to the client’s browser. After that the browser runs the javascript. Basically, because PHP will always be executed before javascript it is impossible to send a javascript variable to php without sending a new request to the server. I would advice following @Cole’s advice and take a look at ajax.

Comment: Yea that's correct, I used AJAX with a POST request and I received the value in the console .. now I need to use it at the front end not at the backend :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from client to server via requests. You can have your javascript call an XHR with the variable as parameter and create a script on your PHP that handles this request.

Comment: Yea that's correct, I used AJAX with a POST request and I received the value in the console .. now I need to use it at the front end not at the backend :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373126/sending-value-from-ajax-to-json-file