# Sending value from AJAX to JSON file

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I need to send value from AJAX to JSON file so I did it into 2 steps

1. Send from AJAX to PHP file
2. Send from PHP file to JSON

The problem that I can't read JSON file at the same page of saving it

Sending value from AJAX to PHP file (IT WORKS FINE)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id:value},
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    });

<?php
    $collectionID = file_get_contents('json.json');
//This php code is in the same page of AJAX, my problem that it doesn't read json at the same time.
//I must refresh the page to read the old value then the AJAX save a new value and I can't read it also now
?>
```

php.php file - write the value into json file (IT WORKS FINE)

```
file_put_contents('json.json', $_POST['id']);
```

I need to send and save the value from AJAX (UP) then read it again into my php code (DOWN) at the same page!!!

I need to do that because I can't send value from JS to PHP direct, so I sent it from client side (JS) and I received into server side (PHP) .. Now I want to receive it back into client side (PHP) to echo the value

Comment: Because I sent it from client side (JS) and I received into server side (PHP) .. Now I want to receive it back into client side (PHP) to echo the value

Comment: Where do you ever write the data to the file? This is all quite confusing. Tell us what your specific problem is

Comment: I also think you think the php will run inside the page in the browser. I could be wrong about that but php and javascript run in 2 completely different environments. Php only runs on server, javascript only runs in the browser

Comment: I really confused :( ...... Could you please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372107/i-need-to-pass-js-var-into-php-var-inside-js-function/47373066#47373066